# Was this scene from the Star Trek Beyond trailer in the film somewhere?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

When I saw this scene, I could not place it. Was it cut from the film?

[image]

Comment: The question "When I saw this scene, I could not place it. Can you?" is asking if someone else can recognize a frame from the trailer in the movie itself.  That requires a yes or no answer.  You are obviously seeking other information, I suggest clarifying your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to TrekCore, the "foggy yorktown" scenes were among the 27 minutes of footage that was trimmed from the final cut.

> [image]
>
> **A foggy view of Yorktown from the December teaser trailer.**
>
> [Nearly Thirty Minutes Cut From TREK BEYOND Final Edit](http://trekcore.com/blog/2016/07/nearly-thirty-minutes-cut-from-trek-beyond-final-edit/)